# Hibernate user update deletes user role

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

The purpose of my project is to have admins/managers/employees/customers. Upon logging the user depending on the role will have these functions:

1. Update employee information in employee list(Managers, Admins)
2. View customer list (Managers, Admins, Employees)
3. Update users own information (Manager, Admin, Employee, Customers)

Issue that I have been stuck on for a few weeks is that when updating any users information, it automatically deletes that users role from the database. This removes their access from the web app.

I've done some research trying to figure this out but haven't found a solid answer. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Employee.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "employee_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;
```

EmployeeController.java -

```
@PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee theEmployee) {

    employeeService.saveEmployee(theEmployee);

    return "redirect:/employee/list";
}
```

EmployeeDaoImpl.java -

```
@Override
public void saveEmployee(Employee theEmployee) {
    // get current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


    // save Employee
    currentSession.update(theEmployee);
}
```

Logs -

```
Hibernate: update employee set address=?, email=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, password=?, phone_number=?, username=?, zipcode=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from employee_roles where employee_id=?
```

edit:

Role.java

```
Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;


public Role() {
}

public Role(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Role{" + "id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
}
}
```

Comment: probably the field `roles` in Employee is null when updating. Try to use break point in your code and see that field before updating employee.

Comment: That would seem to be the case, I added a sysout 
System.out.println("This is the employees roles " + theEmployee.getRoles()); and it returned "This is the employees roles null"

Comment: Can you provide the json, that you're sending?

Comment: I'm not using JSON/Restful for this project atm

Comment: After adding in the jsp file: <form:hidden path="roles"/>. The sysout log returns [Role{id=null, name='Role{id=3'}, Role{id=null, name='name='ROLE_ADMIN'}'}]

Comment: It still deletes the initial row in the database but then inserts two separate rows into roles "name='ROLE_ADMIN' and Role
{id=3 and assigns the users id to those new roles in role_employees.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these code to your Role class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
private Collection<Employee> employees;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I updated the post with the Role class

Comment: Thanks Josep for providing information. I will try to increase my reputation first.

Comment: I added the code but didn't change the outcome. The problem seems to be that the session isn't retaining the users role causing it to return null. Since hibernate sees null it decides to delete the relation in the DB.